# Chartkick Pie chart legend customisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, highcharts, chartkick

I am using highcharts library in chartkick for drawing charts.

I need to customize the legend of the pie chart but I could able to do it.

My code is

```
<%= pie_chart Question.group(:user_id).count %>
```

This results in

[image]

But I need something like

[image]

ie) I need the legends to be displayed separately.

Don't consider the data in the legend, it is nothing but a sample data which may vary in two charts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the default options for a pie chart.

1. Disable data labels: http://jsfiddle.net/qor8fhqb/2/

   ```
   plotOptions: {
     pie: {
       dataLabels: {
         enabled: false
       }
     }
   },
   ```
2. Enable showing the pie series in legend http://jsfiddle.net/qor8fhqb/3/

   ```
   series: [{
     showInLegend: true,
   ```
3. Customise the legend's symbol http://jsfiddle.net/qor8fhqb/4/

   ```
   legend: {
    symbolWidth: 40,
    // symbolHeight: 20,
    squareSymbol: false,
    symbolRadius: 0
   },
   ```

This is config for a pure Highcharts without any wrapper.

Comment: Do you know how to get the pie title on click of a pie of this piechart?